# What exactly does the error "LookupTableSortOrderMustComeAfterParentSortOrder" mean?

Tags: rest, project-server

I'm trying to create an enterprise lookup table in Project Server using the REST API.

If I use the following code (some stuff omitted for brevity and clarity):

```
const lookupDef = {
    name: 'My Table Name',
    masks: [
        {
            Length: 0,
            MaskType: 3,
            Separator: '.'
        }
    ],
    entries: [
        "Entry #1",
        "Entry #2"
    ]
}

const params = {
    parameters: {
        Name: lookupDef.name,
        Masks: lookupDef.masks,
        SortOrder: 0,
        Entries: lookupDef.entries.map(val => {
            return {
                Value: {
                    TextValue: val
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

const uri = `${myWebUrl}/_api/ProjectServer/LookupTables/Add`

httpClient.post(lookupUri, HttpClient.configurations.v1, {
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-RequestDigest': token.FormDigestValue
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(params)
});
```

I get an error:

> 403 - Forbidden: PJClientCallableException: LookupTableSortOrderMustComeAfterParentSortOrder

I tried to look up that error and found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/project/project-server-error-codes#table-13-lookup-table), which really gives no explanation.

I tried adding `SortIndex` to each of the lookup table values by adding

```
Entries: lookupDef.entries.map((val, idx) => {
    return {
        SortIndex: `${idx}`,
        Value: {
            TextValue: val
        }
    }
})
```

when I build the `parameters` payload, but I still get the same error.

What does the error mean, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the `SortIndex` is a 1 based index, so just changing how I built the `Entries` part of the payload fixed it:

```
Entries: lookupDef.entries.map((val, idx) => {
    return {
        SortIndex: `${idx + 1}`,
        Value: {
            TextValue: val
        }
    }
})
```

It does not appear that any other properties of the [`LookupEntryCreationInformation`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Project-docs-pr/blob/main/project/api/LookupEntryCreationInformation.md) object are actually *required*, since that does work. Or rather, that the `SortIndex` is the only required property (other  than the value itself), since it did not work when I omitted the `SortIndex`, but did work the way I settled on with *only* the `SortIndex` and the `Value`.